# MongoDB - Search two fields with two queries

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, search, indexing

It's been a while since I've worked with mongo and I feel I'm losing it with this one.

I have a series of documents in a collection in the form of:

```
{
  _id,
  title: string,
  description: string,
  location: string
  ...
}
```

and I want to search those documents by two queries:

1st query - search in title and description,
2nd query - search in location

it should only return results that match both queries.

Or SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT *
FROM `docs`
WHERE (`title` LIKE '%query_ONE%' OR `description` LIKE '%query_ONE%')
AND `city` LIKE '%query_TWO%'
```

I have pretty much searched and tried every solution here and so far it seems to be a problem with "location" field as it always returns nothing on search/find, while on title / description it works fine. I think my index is bad or something. I admit I'm not too familiar with indexing / more advanced searching, so I'm hoping for some guidance on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: so just do you want something like select * from where table where title='value' and location='value'  ??

Comment: A better description of the query you are trying to execute would really help, are you trying to `find a document whose title or description matches a value and location matches another value` or what?

Comment: why do you've to do it as two queries if you wanted to get results that match both queries ? then it would basically an `and` operation `.find({ title: string,
  description: string,
  location: string})`, if not please share sample docs with req o/p

Comment: I've added an SQL equivalent query. Should have done that from the start.

Comment: @devdrg : Ok now I got it. Please check my answer..

Answer (score 1):

You need to try [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html) :

```
db.docs.find({$or:[{title:'title'}, {description:'des'}], location:'my'})
```

**Collection :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c7"),
    "title" : "title",
    "description" : "des",
    "location" : "my"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfeac84400289966e204380"),
    "title" : "title1",
    "description" : "des1",
    "location" : "my"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfeac8b400289966e2043ec"),
    "title" : "title",
    "description" : "des",
    "location" : "my1"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfead06400289966e204e1e"),
    "title" : "title1",
    "description" : "des1",
    "location" : "my1"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfeae24400289966e2067ad"),
    "title" : "title",
    "description" : "des1",
    "location" : "my"
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfeae2f400289966e206894"),
    "title" : "title1",
    "description" : "des",
    "location" : "my"
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c7"),
    "title" : "title",
    "description" : "des",
    "location" : "my"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfeae24400289966e2067ad"),
    "title" : "title",
    "description" : "des1",
    "location" : "my"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfeae2f400289966e206894"),
    "title" : "title1",
    "description" : "des",
    "location" : "my"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two conditions using an aggregation pipeline. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/ and https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html